# pcl::io::loadPCDFile("2.pcd", *cloud); ERROR

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I am beginner in PointCloud, and I just followed the tutorial in official website, but I can't run the code in Visual Studio 2019 or 2017.

I have tried this in Studio 2019 and 2017 but the result is same. "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application. " Is there any solution for this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>

int main()
{
 pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud(new 
 pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
 pcl::io::loadPCDFile("2.pcd", *cloud);

 system("pause");
 return (0);
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you know if the program starts and crashes during loadPCDFile ? or does it crash even before starting ?

Comment: @Liumatt Hi, It just crashed during loadPCDFile, If I dont type pcl::iio::loadPCDFile, the program still work fine, do you have any idea what happened? thankyou~

Comment: Are you sure that the file "2.pcd" that you try to load exists just next to your executable ?